# c++ k-d tree implementation crashes

Tags: c++, tree, kdtree

I'm trying to implement a simple k-d tree, but I'm either doing something wrong in terms of memory management, or that I'm trying to access something that isn't there (e.i. the program compiles, but crashes when I run it). Here is the part where I believe the problem is coming from:

```
void tree::addpoint (node* leaf, const my_vec &pointdata, int ref)
{
  my_vec center(2);
  int indicator;

  indicator = findquad (leaf, pointdata);

  if ( leaf->child[indicator] == NULL )
  {
    if ( (indicator%2) > 0)
        center[0] = leaf->center[0] + leaf->boxsize/4;
    else
        center[0] = leaf->center[0] - leaf->boxsize/4;
    if ( indicator > 1 )
        center[1] = leaf->center[1] + leaf->boxsize/4;
    else
        center[1] = leaf->center[1] - leaf->boxsize/4;
    leaf->child[indicator] = new node;
    leaf->child[indicator]->point = pointdata;
    leaf->child[indicator]->ref = ref;
    leaf->child[indicator]->center = center;
    leaf->child[indicator]->boxsize = leaf->boxsize/2;
    leaf->child[indicator]->IsReal = true;
    leaf->child[indicator]->child.resize(4);
    for (int i=1; i<4; i++)
        leaf->child[indicator]->child[i] = NULL;
  }
  else
    addpoint (leaf->child[indicator], pointdata, ref);

  if (leaf->IsReal)
  {
    leaf->IsReal = false;
    addpoint (leaf, pointdata, ref);
  }   
}

int tree::findquad(node *leaf, const my_vec& pointdata)
// For a given node 'node', find the proper octraturequadrature for a point located at   'pointdata'.
{
  bool north, east;
  int indicator = 0, end;

  end = pointdata.size() - 1;

  east = pointdata[0] >= leaf->center[0];
  north = pointdata[end] >= leaf->center[1];

  if (east)
    indicator = indicator + 2;
  if (north)
    indicator = indicator + 1;
  return(indicator);
}
```

Comment: On what line does the crash occur?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I don't get a message telling me where did it crash, but if I comment the lines "else addpoint (leaf->child[indicator], pointdata, ref);" so that they are not compiled, the program runs without crashing.

Comment: my question is what am I doing wrong. I'm not very experienced in programming, and I just can't figure out what am I doing wrong.

Comment: I can't read all of this right now, and anyway "teach a man to fish" and all that. You could use a debugger, but you might want to just add printing commands every other line (something like `cerr<<__LINE__<<endl`) and just see where your program crashes. Then you might be able to debug it yourself...